# Typescript array with mixed objects

Tags: typescript

I have 3 routes that receive different parameters.

```js
interface PageFormat<T> {
  page1: string;
  page2: string;
  routeParams: T;
}

interface ARouteFormat { aValue: string; }
const A: React.FC<PageFormat<ARouteFormat>> = () => <div>A</div>;

interface BRouteFormat { bValue: string; }
const B: React.FC<PageFormat<BRouteFormat>> = () => <div>B</div>;

interface CRouteFormat { cValue: string; }
const C: React.FC<PageFormat<CRouteFormat>> = () => <div>C</div>;
```

Also, I have an array with the routes,

```js
interface RouteFormat<Parameters> {
  component: React.FC<PageFormat<Parameters>>
  params?: {
    [key in keyof Parameters]: string;
  }
}

type RouteParameters = RouteFormat<BRouteFormat> | RouteFormat<ARouteFormat> | RouteFormat<CRouteFormat>;

const a: RouteParameters[] = [
  {
    component: A,
    params: { aValue: 'example a' },
  },
  {
    component: B,
    params: { bValue: 'example a' },
  },
  {
    component: C,
    params: { cValue: 'example a' },
  },
];
```

That works, but `params` doesn't match always with  `component`, i.e I can create and element in the array as. But I need to make these the same type.

```js
{
  component: A,
  params: { aValue: 'example a', bValue: 'asdasd' },
},
```

Comment: Unrelated: don't name your type variable `Parameters` as that is now [a built in type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype)

Comment: The problem is that `bValue: 'asdasd'` part is assignable to `RouteParameters` because `|` acts as a union and accepts types that are a little bit of one and a little bit of the other. If you assign each object to an indivdual typed variable that would do what you want. Anther way to do it would be to write a big tybe with a bunch of exclude that determines the correct type  for each element, but that's an even bigger pain than typing each object.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to replace the `params` value in your `RouteFormat` interface so that it matches the generic `Parameters`.

```
interface RouteFormat<Parameters> {
    component: React.FC<PageFormat<Parameters>>
    params: Parameters
}
```

We will now get errors unless all required `params` are provided.

```
const a: RouteParameters[] = [
    {
        component: C,
        params: { cValue: 'example a' }, // ok
    },
    {
        component: C,
        params: { aValue: "a", cValue: "c" } // ok - no error on excess properties
    },
    {
        component: C // error - missing params
    },
    {
        component: C,
        params: {} // error - missing cValue
    },
    {
        component: C,
        params: { aValue: "a" } // error - missing cValue
    }
];
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4BYAKCuADsYkpN0k4AFFAcyQDFoQUMADwAVAHxwA3lTiy4YLkgCMALjgBnGFDqcKlOfMUAmNZu21dMuTgCuDDlBQh1akXoC%20VGvUbM0rAEEECDtefkEpOBQANRQAGxskUy0dUjhPSjQIWk04ALVkdBgAOh4AYSEObj4oAWEgkIYaurEJAF44AAoASjg2iSEAE2AANzEAoQB6YbG9bwYmFjgAIWDQ5ojJOAAjWISkjRSLNIysnPhlguIS8srFDeFVxrDawVa%20rt7%20uCHRsWWpjMxHNKHQFn5WGU1k1wvAtmg9olkuZdOkqGdcmUrkVShUqi86kIoc8Hu8Oj0%20gMgRVpn8QWDfEtoQTBHdHCAkAt1BJpPo5FlwNkkPRsRhcXdqrC2U5OYxuWIrLIFOyXOwUOzZVB1FQMlQYABPMCsZkOGVcj7Mh5CJ7rWESAA%20iBJUoatteMAdTrdhOJ3reIIx8BQBWepo5XIA2gBdD4RxVSeMGAWQWjCmBqAIAGkTcmVTlVWxi8SRcAA5EgAB5OMBxVgoUvpTNwSaTCAAa3j7mzfNkvIMSdwKbTamW3f7ufV%20bUW12xYO5ar4FrUQbXebrY7Pcb8b747gyaFIrgZTHe7zzmn%208R88r1eX9cb6-bndPvZzsgPqaPZXXcEYOCgOAAFo4BAYB1HUHRDBVF8d3ffdB0PdNj1fftzwLdxf3-aBgNA8DIIsK851grdd3HT9hxQ%20D0MvIt9jUfAUHwdIsKgADcLAiCoIRYity7OCtwHQUv2Qk9qMnC9IjoktGPwJsePogg0GYzCWzgWgID-NicOyP8K38CD5BwI1YGAJBtT47so1IIA)